# Drag and drop images

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

With this code I am able to drag and drop an image to the label but now I want to drag that image from the label to another label. How can I do that?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Image img = Image.FromFile(@"D:\test\test.png");
            this.btnImage.Image = img;

            Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\SAURABH\Desktop\Green.ico");
            this.btnImage1.Image = img1;
        }

        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnPic = (Button)sender;
            btnPic.DoDragDrop(btnPic.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

        private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnPic = (Button)sender;
            btnPic.DoDragDrop(btnPic.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

        private void button3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnPic = (Button)sender;
            btnPic.DoDragDrop(btnPic.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

        private void label1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }

        private void label10_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }

        private void label10_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Label picbox = (Label)sender;
            //PictureBox picbox = (PictureBox)sender;
            Graphics g = picbox.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawImage((Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), new Point(0, 0));
        }

        private void label1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Label picbox = (Label)sender;
            //PictureBox picbox = (PictureBox)sender;
            Graphics g = picbox.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawImage((Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `Label`s' DragDrop handler.  You can directly copy the drag and drop operation's 'payload' with code like this:

```
private void Label_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap))) {
        ((Label)sender).Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }
}
```

You might find [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx) on drag and drop useful.

I also noticed in your code that the `MouseDown`, `DragEnter` and `DragDrop` event handers are identical for multiple `Button` and `Label` controls.  You can refactor things a bit by writing each of these handlers once and then registering multiple controls' events to each of these handlers.  For example, you can register your `Label1` and `Label10`'s DragDrop events to the handler I provided above.  Do this in the Designer, or through code:

```
label1.DragDrop += Label_DragDrop;
label10.DragDrop += Label_DragDrop;
```